# jQuery Mobile breaking styling because of min-height

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm building a test mobile website for a client: http://preview.stafforce.co.uk/mobile/

As you can see, upon the loading the website on a mobile device or on the desktop using the correct viewport size you will see a red box with three options. The red box is the page itself told be red by a class of splash. (I had originally had this as a separate DIV that sat ontop of the page using position fixed, but that had several issues with positioning).

On the desktop this works fine, but on the mobile device e.g. iPhone using Safari when the toolbar disappears and/or you scroll/change orientation you get a black bar, this is because the body is appearing as the div is not taking up the full size of the screen (jq mobile uses min-height which is done using the framework to make this happen).

Any ideas on how to fix this? Or had similar issues? Also noticed when doing the transitions that they appear cut off in places again likely attributed to this min-height not getting things correct.

Example:

[image]

**Edit: The reason I have changed the body to black is because when you do the flip transitions, this is what you see behind, and black is the correct colour for the background when doing transitions on phones such as the iPhone.**

Comment: Apart from the landing page content not being centred, it works fine in IE9 mobile (WP 7.5). Can you post a screenshot of your issue? It's a little hard to understand.

Comment: See attached. Also noticed that sometimes the black appears on the side when switching from landscape to portrait again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery mobile enhanced 'listview' and keep your content in DIV with data-role='content'. 
Jquery mobile will make your content fullscreen.
You should not style listview or anything else manually.

Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nachiket/YSp3x/

I haven't set icons and your logo, but you will get idea.
If possible use [Jquery mobile Theme Roller](http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php) for base styling, and do customizations on top of it.

**EDIT:** 
You can set color on div which has data-role="page".

Like:

```
.myPage {
    background-color:#ff0000; 
    background-image:none;
}​
```

And in HTML

```
<div data-role="page" class="myPage">
```

I have already updated jsfiddle link.

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue! As the page itself and NOT the content needs to be red so in your example I would get the same result.